# Spring Custom Namespace - Use Cases

Tags: spring, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to understand where Spring custom namespace can help -- like simplifying somethings in a large application.

The last comment on [this blog](http://blog.springsource.com/2006/08/28/creating-a-spring-20-namespace-use-springs-abstractbeandefintionparser-hierarchy/) was intriguing:

> I'm building out a namespace at work for making service and bean management more standardized within the development group. This also tends to make things simpler and not have them worry if I change the standard for a bean definition or maybe use different factories for different types of services in the future. I'm still figuring out how to best utilize this new mechanism, though.

Trying to understand how custom namespace helps in bean management.

If you developed custom namespaces, could you please post how custom namespaces helped in your development.

Comment: Might wanna check this blog: http://javamoods.blogspot.com/2009/09/spring-use-custom-namespaces.html

Comment: @abalogh - thanks for the link. that's a great post!

Comment: Adding as answer then :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://javamoods.blogspot.com/2009/09/spring-use-custom-namespaces.html) blog has a great post about using custom namespaces and gives you a few examples as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [github repo](https://github.com/codelooru/springmvc/tree/master/NamespaceHandling) for a working example of spring's custom namespace handling.

Or [this article](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/xml-custom.html) on spring io.